# Remove any of multiple characters at beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the following characters: `[`, `]`, `"`, `\` if any are at the beginning or end of a string, but not if they are in the middle.

So, if the string is `""\[\]][hello" world "\[\"]]`, I'd like it to become, `hello" world`

I can't figure out how to do it.  I've tried these and many others and none seems to work:

```
string.replace(/^[\[+|\]+|\"+|\\+]$,"")
string.replace(/^[\[+\]+\"+\\+]$/,"")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you need ? https://regex101.com/r/ny4UCT/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You need two alternatives, one for the beginning and another for the end. Each should then be a character set in `[]` listing all the characters you want to remove.

You also need the `g` modifier to replace twice in the same string.

```js
let string = '""\[\]][hello" world "\[\"]]';

console.log(string.replace(/^["\[\]\\]+|["\[\]\\]+$/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I split the problem into following subproblems:

1. Find these characters at the start of a string
2. Find these characters at the end of a string

I came up with following regex-patterns to solve these:

1. /(^["\[]]+)/g
2. /["\[]]+$/g

When working with regex, I recommend following site: regexr.com/6d193